# Miking 2 actors in a stationary car.

Tags: cars, location-recording, microphone-positioning

Hey,

In a few weeks time I'll be recording production sound for a film in which the actors are sat in a parked car for about 80% of the time.
In the film the interact mainly with one another, but do also interact with actors on the outside of the car.
The car we have is an old Volvo station wagon, the big boxy one from the late 80s.

I was considering miking them in the following way-

2 Lav, mounted above each actors' head on the ceiling of the car, wirelessly connected to my recorder

A shotgun/boom combo in case the need to get out of the car during a take... 
(I should be able to stand out of shot outside the vehicle.)

Does anybody else have further suggestions?

Thanks,

Kurt

Answer (score 2):

Mic the actors with two wired omnis, pop a third omni just above the rear view mirror, and then boom for when the actors talk to people outside the vehicle. so that you have a different  perspective.

Comment: by the way, which omnis would you recommend?
I could get access to 2 Sanken COS11 lavs and I own a Rode NT1-A...

Is this a combination I could make work?


Comment: I would use DPA 4060s, or if the budget was tight AT803Bs.  The Sankens will work well, but the Rode is far too large, and will get in shot as well as pick up far too much vibration.  I suggest hiring a third COS11.

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

Seems like a reasonable way to do it. Some questions:

1. Why don't you wire the actors themselves? To get 'better' acoustics?
2. Do you really need to go wireless? I'd rather go wired if the car is stationary. If you do need to go wireless, make sure the transmitters are outside the car.
3. I would put an extra 'plant' cardiod microphone in between the actors. This gives you a little room sound and can serve as a backup or alternate perspective track.

Hope this helps!

Arnoud

Comment: Plant Microphone can be placed on the sun visor or on the shift lever too.

Comment: 1.
The Actors do some vigorous movement while sitting in the car...
I will definitely run into rubbing/'zuzzing' issues
2. good tip on the transmitters outside the car

